# GAE: Datastore Transaction collision. Retrying... happens frequently

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE Python 2.7 Standard with Datastore.

The problem is Datastore is throwing transaction collision too often.

I wrote a simple test code. (I know this kind of code doesn't exist. It's just a test code.)
I am just updating one entity several times in a transaction.

I don't think anything will possibly collide since I am just updating the same schedule entity.

But looking at the logging, "Transaction collision. Retrying..."  is happening several times.

What is the reason Datastore is causing transaction collision?

```py
from google.appengine.ext import db

# get any entity
schedule = Schedule.get('entity_key')

def _txn(schedule):
    schedule.save()
    schedule.save()
    schedule.save()
    schedule.save()
xg_on = db.create_transaction_options(xg=True)
for i in range(0, 100):
    logging.info(i)
    db.run_in_transaction_options(xg_on,
                                  _txn,
                                  schedule)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you try to update an entity more than once per second, this could lead to latency issues, timeouts, and other types of error.

You can take a look at the best practices for datastore [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_an_entity) and see how to prevent this kind of error in the future.